# Display sdl is not available

Tags: android, 18.10, android-emulator

[image: Terminal]

I install Android Operating System in Computer(Ubuntu), But when I run command `sudo qemu-android`, then give sdl display not found the output.

Comment: check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231173/325108)

Answer (score 0):

Did u convert the .rpm package to .deb via alien? on ubuntu and debian its the failsafe way to resolve all dependancies, If installing as rpm some dependencies have no valid candidate.

```
sudo apt install alien
sudo alien -ci android-x86-8.1-r2.i686.rpm
```